# Semantic clustering

Tags: algorithms, strings, string-metrics, natural-language-processing, ontologies

I have a very specific question about semantic clustering.

I have a list of words/phrases. I want to run an intelligent semantic clustering algorithm on this list. Please let me know what the available options are. Definitely I am looking for NLP based algorithms.

Simple, open-source, easy-to-use solutions will be highly appreciated. The semantic part is extremely important here.

Comment: Did you already have a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity)? Assuming this is what you mean by semantic clustering; it wouldn't hurt to clarify.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Juho. Let me try to clarify a bit.

I have a file containing several titles and I want a semantic clustering of these titles.

Though the dataset is essentially one dimensional, some of the titles have two or more words and/or special characters like /-"#&'()*% etc.

Please let me know if there is any easy solution to this problem.

Best regards,

Comment: Welcome! That is by far not a "very specific question". It is also ill-posed: without a semantic metric, you can not cluster (clustering itself is no different from non-semantic clustering). You can not get to a semantic metric without stating what the semantics of your strings are, what you consider similar, etc. It is furthermore not clear what "intelligent" and "easy" should mean here. You have to give us some more to work with, and I suggest you do some research yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Raphael. Being a researcher myself, I know that the question is ill-posed. Unfortunately, I do not have enough information to add clarity to the problem description. I am yet to locate reliable software packages to deal with non-numeric data. That is why I was thinking if any standard NLP based solution is already available. The solution should consider the English meaning of the titles while clustering. Regards,

Comment: More specifically, if there exists a  software package, which considers the English meaning of the titles and can directly produce the clusters from the input file containing the titles, that will be ideal for my purpose.

Best regards,

Comment: So you are only interested in already implemented libraries? In that case, the question would be offtopic here.

Comment: Not exactly. I am interested in finding a solution to this problem. If a solution already exists, that will be great. Please advise me on where I should post this question. Best regards,

Comment: @Dibyendu: I think your question needs help before it fits any site, even though I think it is a reasonable question.  Here, you will get theoretical responses (education level), which will ask you for metrics because - well, you need them for the problem to make sense.  StackOverflow, Programmers, and related would want to know system/development language/etc. because they expect you'd be developing the product.  Linguistics would be closer, but they're leary of glottochronology and similar algorithms as meaningful and don't make use of clustering for their study.  (cont..)

Comment: @Dibyendu: However, I think it's clear what you'd like.  You seem to want professional packages for semantic clustering based on professional, likely experimentally-tuned not-necessarily-theoretical metrics that gives a good starting position.  But that's the stuff of Google, Siri, and other products, and is worth good money.  Instead, I think your best effort is to mine research projects or write a little web-crawler to build your own database and start there.  Ask here and the other sites for specific theoretical or practical help as it may arise.  Sorry if this seems a lot of work...

Comment: Hello ex0du5,

Thanks a lot for the clarification. I did not know the kind of questions one should ask here. Sorry about that.

Best regards,

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of different approaches that you could take. While the commenters are right, coming up with a distance metric is important, based on my own experience, finding good representations of your words/phrases is going to be significantly more important.

Most of the "semantic" clustering algorithms that immediately come to mind are document level, not word or phrase level. This would include things like the closely related [LSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis), [PLSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_latent_semantic_analysis), and [LDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation), or neural network based approaches such as [Semantic Hashing](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/sh.pdf). This list is by no means exhaustive, any unsupervised machine learning approach to topic modeling could probably be thought of as doing document level semantic clustering.

I'm not sure how well the above approaches would work at the phrase level. I'm not going to say they won't, but I suspect the performance would be quite poor, since you are going to have a bunch of really (really!) sparse [term vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model).

At the phrase level there are several techniques that seem promising. Simple techniques, such as just clustering n-grams are unlikely to yield useful results, so we'll rule that out right off the bat. A significantly better option would be to use learned word/phrase embeddings and then run some standard clustering algorithm (such as k-means) over these. [Collobert](http://ronan.collobert.com/) and [Weston](http://www.thespermwhale.com/jaseweston/) have done some really interesting work in this vein. Their paper [A Unified Architecture for Natural Language Processing: Deep Neural Networks with Multitask Learning](http://ronan.collobert.com/pub/matos/2008_nlp_icml.pdf) or the related work [Word representations: A simple and general method for semi-supervised learning](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lisa/pointeurs/turian-wordrepresentations-acl10.pdf) by Turian et al would be a good place to start. Turian has a number of different word embeddings available on his website for download [here](http://metaoptimize.com/projects/wordreprs/), which may allow you to sidestep the overhead involved in learning such embeddings yourself.

Another option is to hand engineer features or a distance metric using a resource such as [Wordnet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/). This certainly seems like a reasonable approach and a google search for "wordnet semantic distance" yields numerous results. I can't point you in any particular direction here though. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hm, n-grams may be useful to check whether two words occur in similar contexts.