# Document clustering for summarization

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, natural-language-processing, cluster

I am curious as to what steps one would reasonably need to take to perform an extraction-based text summarizer.

I've taken a look at some papers I've found on Google such as [this one](https://wwws.cs.umn.edu/tech_reports_upload/tr2000/00-034.ps), which explains that UPGMA is the best clustering algorithm (out of the tested set). I've also found [this one](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/I/I05/I05-2004.pdf) to be interesting, regarding single and multi-document summarization.

I'm unclear as to whether I'd need to combine these techniques for summarization or whether it would suffice to use a tool like Gensim to model a corpus of documents and just extract the sentences with the highest vector values.

Comment: [Related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2922/semantic-clustering/2924#2924).